# How can I forcefully remove a stack and all its informations in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I've deleted my stack due to some problems of the deployment pipeline and after I released changes. When it reached the Deploy step, I got an error in cloud formation like it was not possible to find the service (from the stack deleted before) and occurred a Validation exception (with HTTP status 400).

So, I released changes again and got stuck at the same point, but with a different error: the stack is with ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and cannot be updated.

Is there any way to forcefully delete all contents of a stack, with no remaining status or resources?

**EDIT**

@Marcin, after the stack exclusion, I got the above:

```
    Timestamp
Logical ID
Status
Status reason
2020-08-13 09:53:44 UTC-0300    service-paguecontascartoes-listapaguecontas ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   -
2020-08-13 09:53:43 UTC-0300    CloudWatchLogGroup  DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-08-13 09:53:43 UTC-0300    TargetGroup DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-08-13 09:53:43 UTC-0300    LoadBalancer    DELETE_COMPLETE -
2020-08-13 09:53:43 UTC-0300    CloudWatchLogGroup  DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-08-13 09:53:43 UTC-0300    TargetGroup DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-08-13 09:53:33 UTC-0300    service-paguecontascartoes-listapaguecontas ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [CloudWatchLogGroup, LoadBalancer, TargetGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.
2020-08-13 09:53:32 UTC-0300    TargetGroup CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled
2020-08-13 09:53:32 UTC-0300    CloudWatchLogGroup  CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled
2020-08-13 09:53:32 UTC-0300    TargetGroup CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-08-13 09:53:32 UTC-0300    CloudWatchLogGroup  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
2020-08-13 09:53:32 UTC-0300    LoadBalancer    CREATE_FAILED   nlb-jdk8-listapaguecontas already exists
2020-08-13 09:53:31 UTC-0300    TargetGroup CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-08-13 09:53:31 UTC-0300    CloudWatchLogGroup  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-08-13 09:53:31 UTC-0300    LoadBalancer    CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
2020-08-13 09:53:27 UTC-0300    service-paguecontascartoes-listapaguecontas CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
2020-08-13 09:52:42 UTC-0300    service-paguecontascartoes-listapaguecontas REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

And I have to delete it again

Comment: I guess you deleted the role for CP used to create your stacks?

Answer (score 0):

> the stack is with ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and cannot be updated.

A stack in `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` can only be deleted. You can't updated nor [fix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-describing-stacks.html) it:

> When in this state, **only a delete operation** can be performed.